# Getting noClassDefFoundError for an eventuate program

Tags: java, spring, maven

In an eventuate program, getting below error, I doubt some dependency is missing or version issue.

Actually I followed https://github.com/eventuate-examples/eventuate-examples-java-spring-todo-list and tried to build the project using maven, but it doesn't work.

Or if you guys have a sample eventuate 'event driven' based project, please share it to me.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class io.eventuate.javaclient.spring.common.EventuateCommonConfiguration
at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:510)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/eventuate/MissingApplyEventMethodStrategy
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.eventuate.MissingApplyEventMethodStrategy
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

And below is the **POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.xyz.services</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-stub</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.eventuate.local.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-local-java-cdc-mysql-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.networknt/eventuate-cdccore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-cdccore</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.eventuate.client.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-client-java-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>eventuate-release</id>
        <url>http://mavenrepo.eventuate.io/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories></project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that somehow you are using a mixture of new (needs MissingApplyEventMethodStrategy) and old (doesn't provide MissingApplyEventMethodStrategy) Eventuate libraries.

In particular, 0.11.0.RELEASE is rather old. Try upgrading to the latest 0.17.0.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks, this issue is resolved, but another issue has come, which can check.